# Connecting to socket to get data from it

Tags: java, sockets, byte

I'm trying to connect to a web socket (Details: [here](http://registrars.nominet.org.uk/namespace/uk/registration-and-domain-management/query-tools/whois2) ) to get information back from it.

As you can see I need clients IP address and so on, here's what I have so far:

```
        //client IP address
        //is client behind something?
        String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");  
        if (ipAddress == null) {  
                ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  
        }

            String socketAddress = "whois.nic.uk";
            int socketPort = 1043;

            Socket socket = new Socket(socketAddress, socketPort);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            //for every domain loop
            String singleDomain = "google.co.uk"; //just an example
            //<hostname of client> <IP address of client> <domain to query><cr><lf>
                String whoIs2 = ipAddress + " " + ipAddress + " " + singleDomain + "\r\n";

                //convert message to bytes
                byte[] whoIs2B = whoIs2.getBytes();
```

Basically I'm not sure how to sent the whoIs2B (byte version to the socket if that makes sense?). I then need to change the byte response to text, that's all I need.

Note: Don't mind try / catches since I had to delete some unnecessary info to make it easier to see what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

To send the bytes down the socket you need to write to the underlying stream 'out'.

You'd do something similar for the input stream.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets

Comment: Just realised I need to use out.write() etc. But I'm still a bit lost to get the response from the socket.

Comment: Does (String) in.readObject() work? Or you could read use readByte() in a while loop (while there are bytes available) and convert the bytes to a String